# How to add any NSString data in Keychain in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, keychain

I want to add some data in the Keychain in iOS. I am not worried about the security just wanted to store some string permanently some where(Keychain) which can be consistent even if user uninstalled the application. I am not storing any password, all the example in the Web are only showing how to store the password. I am planning to use the kSecClassKey attribute to store the string. Please guide me in the correct direction. Any sample code will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you consider using NSUserDefaults instead?

Comment: NSUserDefaults will be not be there if user uninstall the application, therefore can't use the NSUserDefaults.

Comment: iCloud key/value store is another possible solution. Not difficult to use but there may be some users that are not using iCloud. There are keychain storage classes other than passwords see the docs (allocate substantial time).

Answer (score 1):

I've used SFHF Keychain lib ( https://github.com/kamiro/SFHFKeychainUtils ). It's really easy to use and works fine.

Here an example to use

```
NSString* username = @"myValue1";
NSString* service = @"com.organization.appname.myValue1";
NSString* valueToStore = @"....";

// Add/Update valute to keychain
NSError* anyStoringError = NULL;
BOOL stored = [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:username andPassword:valueToStore forServiceName:service updateExisting:YES error:&anyStoringError];

// Get value from keychain
NSString *storedValue = [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:username andServiceName:service error:&anyStoringError];

// Remove value from keychain
BOOL valueRemoved = [SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:username andServiceName:service error:&anyStoringError];
```

Hope it helps